# i want to mass follow twitter accounts but i got error that said i've requested to follow

Tags: twitterapi-python

So i want to mass follow people on Twitter with my account

but im kinda confused because i don't know how to fix the error, like i've requested to follow the "user", so what i want to do is skip the user if ive requested to follow them, but i dont know how to fix it, here's the code

`

```
following = api.get_friend_ids(screen_name = "2Wild2Crazy")

friends = api.get_friends(screen_name = "2Wild2Crazy", count = 200)

for i in range(len(friends)):
    print(""" " """, friends[i].screen_name, """ " """) 


#mass follow the people who follow 2Wild2Crazy
for i in range(len(friends)):
    api.create_friendship(screen_name = friends[i].screen_name)
```

`

Comment: here's the error
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
160 - You've already requested to follow "user".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
#mass follow the people who follow 2Wild2Crazy
for i in range(len(friends)):
    try:
        api.create_friendship(screen_name = friends[i].screen_name)
    except tweepy.errors.Forbidden:
        print("Already following user: {}, skipping.".format(friends[i].screen_name))
```

Might have to `import tweepy` to be able to except the error. If you don't like the print command you can replace it with `pass` that will tell python to just ignore that specific error.